# Is there any way to set the user agent in PhantomJS using PhantomJSDriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, user-agent

I've been looking for a way to change the user agent in my PhantomJSDriver and haven't found one so far.  There's a blurb in the Selenium docs about the Firefox driver but I'm using PhantomJS.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user agent cannot be directly set on the driver. Specifically, the driver looks for the `"phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"` property, so it has to be set before invoking the driver.

Here is an example of a user agent that approximates the capabilities of PhantomJS 1.x best:

```
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.41 Safari/535.1";
System.setProperty("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", userAgent);
```

Comment: Below is my code but not working for me :
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.41 Safari/535.1";
  
File file = new File("D:/req/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe");
System.setProperty("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", userAgent);
System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", file.getAbsolutePath());  
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();

Comment: @Ninjajava You can certainly [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) specific to version 2.1.1. I can't help you there.

Answer (score 1):

```
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();

dc.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_PAGE_SETTINGS_PREFIX + "userAgent", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36");

new PhantomJSDriver(dc);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the recent `PhantomJSDriver`, a better approach is setting the user agent via capabilities:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0");
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
```

Setting the property via `System.setProperty()` appears to be no longer working.